# Delete specific data from specific entity from core data in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two entity in my core data named "History" and "Favorite". i want to delete some specific data like "Dhaka" from "History" entity. How to delete this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

```
NSString* aType = @"History";
NSString *tp = @"Dhaka";

NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:aType inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(type == %@)",tp ]; //where type is the attribute
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray* ar = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@@@@@  Data from DB  : %@",ar);
for(id anObj in ar){
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:anObj];
}
[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

predicate=nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [objAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"History"];
    NSArray  *recordArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]];
    objDataClass = [recordArray objectAtIndex:0];  // here objDataClass is a instance of DataClass derived from NSObject which define column name
    [context deleteObject:objDataClass]; // Delete particular data with index

    if ([context hasChanges])
    {
        [context save:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Object Deleted.....");
    }
```

Hope it will help you. :)